# Changing subtitle format with ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, subtitles

How can I change the subtitle format of a movie to .srt for example?

I have any movie (sound, video and an embedded subtitle). I just want to change the subtitles to .srt while leaving everything else the same. If there is a better way to do that than with ffmpeg, then I'd be fine with that too.

**Current state**

audio codec: x, video codec: y, subtitle format: z

**Desired state**

audio codec: x, video codec: y, subtitle format: .srt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FFmpeg has a SubRip encoder, so

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -c:s srt out.mkv
```

Comment: Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:2 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:2 (dvd_subtitle (dvdsub) -> subrip (srt))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:2 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36327919/5726027).

Comment: Full list of subtitle formats supported by `ffmpeg`: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Subtitle-Formats

Comment: `webvtt` for `VTT` fonts

Answer (score 8):

Assuming 'z' is a supported format, something as simple as this should work:

```
ffmpeg -i input.z output.srt
```

List your codecs with     **ffmpeg -codecs** to make sure your 'z' type is supported.

Comment: `webvtt` for `VTT` fonts

Answer (score 2):

You can try to convert the subtitles using a simple tool called Avidemux. I've used it before and it works fine. Find more about it [here](http://en.flossmanuals.net/Avidemux/ExtractingDVDSubtitles/).